# Combine TIME_FLOOR and MILLIS_TO_TIMESTAMP in Apache Druid SQL query to get epoch timestamp

Tags: sql, timestamp, epoch, druid

Could you please help me to figure out Apache Druid SQL request to get response with timestamp in milliseconds.

```
SELECT
"c_id", TIME_FLOOR("__time", 'PT24H') as __time, SUM(active_conn) as active_conn
FROM "mock_data"
WHERE "__time" BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2021-03-03 00:00:00' AND TIMESTAMP '2021-03-18 00:00:00' AND "c_id" IN (0,3)  AND "customer_id" = 8526137
GROUP BY 1,2
```

getting

```
[["4","2021-03-18T00:00:00.000Z",639477945]]
```

want

```
[["4",1614776400000,639477945]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use TIMESTAMP_TO_MILLIS(__time)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might improve your answer with an example that reflects the question code.

Comment: It works! TIMESTAMP_TO_MILLIS(TIME_FLOOR("__time", 'PT24H')) as __time,